# Django / Assigning a value to form.instance in views.py

Tags: python, django

Note that I am new in Django. I have been trying to give value for the 'post' instance of the form. What I want to do is link my comment to a specific post. I could link my comment to author with requesting a user that is currently logged in but cannot set the related post. I got two options for urls.py:

1. First one is setting the path to `<int:pk>` which gives an error `'int' is not iterable`.
2. second one is to set
   to `<pk>` which gives an error `Cannot resolve keyword '1' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, comments, content, date_posted, id, title`

```
## my views.py

class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['content']

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.post = Post.objects.filter(self.kwargs['pk']).first()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

```
## my models.py

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)  


    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

```
## my urls.py

path('post/<pk>/comment/', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name="comment-create")
```

Comment: hello! I edited your question because `<pk>` was being interpreted as markdown and not showing up correctly and the formatting had a pretty dense paragraph. If I changed the meaning of your question please edit again and let me know I messed up.  Hope you find someone who can help :)

Comment: Thanks, I am newbie in this kind of forums and programming; therefore, I can mess up sometimes :)

Answer (score 3):

You're not calling `.filter()` correctly, you need to pass keyword arguments.

```
form.instance.post = Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```